# Using socket.io or node.js to make chat applications?

Tags: node.js, chat, socket.io

I pretty much don't know anything about these two.  Which one is better/more efficient and why?

Also I looked at the node.js example and noticed that they create a server for the chatroom/chat.

Does that mean I need to create a new server for every chat/chatroom or is there a better/more efficient way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket.io is a library which utilizes node.js. Think of node.js as an javascript on the server. Socket.io provides modules for websocket servers (server-side) and websocket clients (client-side).

I do not entirely understand your question about creating a new server for every chat/chatroom. That's entirely up to you.

Comment: well the chat/chatroom was being listened by a node server.  I was wondering if I should start a new server for each chat/chatroom ?

Comment: @Derek Since the whole point of Node and its evented workflow is to handle large numbers of concurrent connections, I'd say you probably don't want a new server for each chat--unless you need/want it for some other reason. There are a lot of articles/tutorials on chat applications built on Node.js, give Google a search.